# Spring boot bean into bean injection methodology

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot

Can anyone tell me if there is a difference (in terms of spring bean injection and respecting singleton conditions or any other spring boot magic) in these two spring boot application classes?

```
@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
public UserService userService(Foo foo){
    return new UserService(foo);
}

@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
public Foo foo(){
    return new Foo();
}
```

AND  calling not declaring **Foo** as a method parameter on **userService()** but rather injecting it via a direct method call to **foo()**

```
@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
public UserService userService(){
    return new UserService(foo());
}

@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
public Foo foo(){
    return new Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference. One might think, you would get a new bean instance everytime you call `foo()` in that configuration class, but the way Spring works in that case is, it creates a proxy for that configuration class which intercepts all method calls. The proxy then checks, if there is already a bean of type `Foo`, if so it returns the existing instance, otherwise the method call is delegated to the implementation and a new bean is created.

Code style wise, however, i think in your first example the dependency to the `Foo` bean is more clearly marked than in the second example.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree that the first style is clearly marked however we have always gone with the second style because it allows us to CTRL-click in intellij to quick browse to the foo() injector... thereby quickly traversing the dependency injection tree.