# Spring Boot. Get bean as response to local bean method call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I work on `@Configuration` class and `masterTransactionManager` bean needs to be injected with `masterDataSource` bean. I found example https://www.codeday.top/2017/07/08/31074.html and it not works.

Here simplified example class

```
@Configuration
public class MasterDataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource masterDataSource() {
        DruidDataSource dataSource = new DruidDataSource();
        ...
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSourceTransactionManager masterTransactionManager() {

        /*
        * Spring not injects bean here, instead
        * it just get new instance
        * of DataSource object
        */
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(masterDataSource());
    }
}
```

I was able to fix this with passing bean reference as argument:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSourceTransactionManager masterTransactionManager(
    @Qualifier("schmodelAuditDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

    /*
    * Now bean injected, and everything works as it should
    */
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

Now the question is: how could it work `new DataSourceTransactionManager(masterDataSource())`? I never saw before that Spring can return bean on method call like in first example. Is this proper solution to get the bean? If this proper call, then why it not works for me?

I was not able to find a lot about such bean call method, though in thread [Spring boot bean into bean injection methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511451/spring-boot-bean-into-bean-injection-methodology) mentioned it should work. While in my case it is not.

**Update: what error I see**

The error I get in first case is

Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException

also in debug mode I see the instance of bean on spring bean initiation call is different, from the returning when my class calls `masterDataSource()` method.

The application starts without errors. I get error when start using beans instantiated (write data to database). I think this is result of not proper bean (is it bean at all, not sure) returned when called `masterDataSource()`

Comment: If you inject a bean then use `@Autowired` or `@Inject` annotation in spring.

Comment: Ok, I use this, but the question I ask about different thing. How could the method call like masterDataSource() return the bean, instead of just new object instance?

Comment: What error does the first case display?

Comment: See my post update with error description

Answer (score 0):

Before answer the question I need to clear what is `Autowiring`?

Spring managed their bean and lifecycle inside `application context` which is a container. `Application context` is a container which contain bean.
When the application context bootstrapped the beans also instantiated by their defined [scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) (**singleton**, **prototype**, **request**, **session**, **global-session**).

Spring's default scope is singleton refers it instantiate at once and shared the object (usually a cached object) within application context.

Autowire happens inject a beans instance to another bean.It means where we inject and what we inject -- both should be beans and lived in `Spring IoC container` *(Application Context)*.

Now come to you question. If you autowire a bean, in fact your instantiated object (instantiated by spring) is set here.If you call some method like `masterDataSource()` in your example:-

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource masterDataSource() {
    DruidDataSource dataSource = new DruidDataSource();
    ...
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSourceTransactionManager masterTransactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(masterDataSource());
}
```

Then `masterDataSource()` also create a new object and set (Injected) to `DataSourceTransactionManager` constructor.

So bottom line is if you used `@Autowired` then you get spring managed (lifecycle) bean/object and if you called `masterDataSource()` then you just create a new object apart from spring managed object.